# breakpoints on django-rest-framework project in vscode are not hit in debug mode

Tags: django, debugging, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

I have django-rest project on my vscode.The problem is that when I run the project in debug mode the breakpoints are not catched!!. I just get response without being stopped on that specific breakpoint.

This is my launch.json file

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

BTW I send the requests by swagger! 
I have also tried postman and got the same result!
(just got the response without the code being stopped on this view ) 
I send the requests to ManageUserView

[image: And this is the view that I send request to]

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar issue. However, when I set "justMyCode" to false, the debugger halts at breakpoints right before an HTTP request is dispatched.